# USDPython 0.64 - Convert FBX to USD (with Morph Targets)

Tags: arkit, usdz, usd

Goal:
Convert FBX to USD (with Morph Targets)

Tried:

1 - Reality converter
FBX to USD worked, but not Morph Targets.
From what I researched,  Reality converter is using USDPython 0.62, which doesnt support Morph targets.
Would be great if apple update Reality converter to suppport  0.64 with Morph Targets.

2- USDPython 0.64
USDZconvert command for FBX to USD worked, but not Morph Targets
Looks like the script that supports  FBX to USD is usdStageWithFbx.py (inside example folder). I have seen no documentation on how to run this script.

Can someone  help out with step by step instructions on ow to run this script?

Cheers to all!